# I'm unable to accept friend request from other users in my Django social site

Tags: python, django, django-models

unable to accept friend requests in my web app
below are the errors that I'm getting when I'm trying to accept the friend request.

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/friend-request/accept/5/
>
> Django Version: 2.1 Python Version: 3.8.10 Installed Applications:
> ['users.apps.UsersConfig',  'feed.apps.FeedConfig',  'crispy_forms',
> 'stdimage',  'django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth',
> 'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions',
> 'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles'] Installed
> Middleware: ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py"
> in _execute
> 85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py"
> in execute
> 296.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>
> The above exception (no such table: main.users_profile__old) was the
> direct cause of the following exception:
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
> 34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
> in _get_response
> 126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
> in _get_response
> 124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
> 21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/rohan/ByteWalk-master/users/views.py" in
> accept_friend_request
> 88.     user1.profile.friends.add(user2.profile)
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py"
> in add
> 926.                 self._add_items(self.source_field_name, self.target_field_name, *objs)
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py"
> in _add_items
> 1088.                     self.through._default_manager.using(db).bulk_create([
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
> in bulk_create
> 465.                 ids = self._batched_insert(objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size)
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
> in _batched_insert
> 1152.                 self._insert(item, fields=fields, using=self.db)
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
> in _insert
> 1133.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py"
> in execute_sql
> 1285.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py"
> in execute
> 100.             return super().execute(sql, params)
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py"
> in execute
> 68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py"
> in _execute_with_wrappers
> 77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py"
> in _execute
> 85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py"
> in **exit**
> 89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py"
> in _execute
> 85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
> File
> "/home/rohan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ByteWalk-master/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py"
> in execute
> 296.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>
> Exception Type: OperationalError at /users/friend-request/accept/5/
> Exception Value: no such table: main.users_profile__old

> views.py

```
import random
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from feed.models import Post
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm
from .models import Profile, FriendRequest

User = get_user_model()


@login_required
def users_list(request):
    users = Profile.objects.exclude(user=request.user)
    sent_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user)
    sent_to = []
    friends = []
    for user in users:
        friend = user.friends.all()
        for f in friend:
            if f in friends:
                friend = friend.exclude(user=f.user)
        friends += friend
    my_friends = request.user.profile.friends.all()
    for i in my_friends:
        if i in friends:
            friends.remove(i)
    if request.user.profile in friends:
        friends.remove(request.user.profile)
    random_list = random.sample(list(users), min(len(list(users)), 10))
    for r in random_list:
        if r in friends:
            random_list.remove(r)
    friends += random_list
    for i in my_friends:
        if i in friends:
            friends.remove(i)
    for se in sent_friend_requests:
        sent_to.append(se.to_user)
    context = {
        'users': friends,
        'sent': sent_to
    }
    return render(request, "users/users_list.html", context)


def friend_list(request):
    p = request.user.profile
    friends = p.friends.all()
    context = {
        'friends': friends
    }
    return render(request, "users/friend_list.html", context)


@login_required
def send_friend_request(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    frequest, created = FriendRequest.objects.get_or_create(
        from_user=request.user,
        to_user=user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/users/{}'.format(user.profile.slug))


@login_required
def cancel_friend_request(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    frequest = FriendRequest.objects.filter(
        from_user=request.user,
        to_user=user).first()
    frequest.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/users/{}'.format(user.profile.slug))


@login_required
def accept_friend_request(request, id):
    from_user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    frequest = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=from_user, to_user=request.user).first()
    user1 = frequest.to_user
    user2 = from_user
    user1.profile.friends.add(user2.profile)
    user2.profile.friends.add(user1.profile)
    if FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, to_user=from_user).first():
        request_rev = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, to_user=from_user).first()
        request_rev.delete()
    frequest.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/users/{}'.format(request.user.profile.slug))


@login_required
def delete_friend_request(request, id):
    from_user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    frequest = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=from_user, to_user=request.user).first()
    frequest.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/users/{}'.format(request.user.profile.slug))


def delete_friend(request, id):
    user_profile = request.user.profile
    friend_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=id)
    user_profile.friends.remove(friend_profile)
    friend_profile.friends.remove(user_profile)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/users/{}'.format(friend_profile.slug))


@login_required
def profile_view(request, slug):
    p = Profile.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    u = p.user
    sent_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=p.user)
    rec_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(to_user=p.user)
    user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user_name=u)

    friends = p.friends.all()

    # is this user our friend
    button_status = 'none'
    if p not in request.user.profile.friends.all():
        button_status = 'not_friend'

        # if we have sent him a friend request
        if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
                from_user=request.user).filter(to_user=p.user)) == 1:
            button_status = 'friend_request_sent'

        # if we have recieved a friend request
        if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
                from_user=p.user).filter(to_user=request.user)) == 1:
            button_status = 'friend_request_received'

    context = {
        'u': u,
        'button_status': button_status,
        'friends_list': friends,
        'sent_friend_requests': sent_friend_requests,
        'rec_friend_requests': rec_friend_requests,
        'post_count': user_posts.count
    }

    return render(request, "users/profile.html", context)


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You can now login!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('my_profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/edit_profile.html', context)


@login_required
def my_profile(request):
    p = request.user.profile
    you = p.user
    sent_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=you)
    rec_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(to_user=you)
    user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user_name=you)
    friends = p.friends.all()

    # is this user our friend
    button_status = 'none'
    if p not in request.user.profile.friends.all():
        button_status = 'not_friend'

        # if we have sent him a friend request
        if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
                from_user=request.user).filter(to_user=you)) == 1:
            button_status = 'friend_request_sent'

        if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
                from_user=p.user).filter(to_user=request.user)) == 1:
            button_status = 'friend_request_received'

    context = {
        'u': you,
        'button_status': button_status,
        'friends_list': friends,
        'sent_friend_requests': sent_friend_requests,
        'rec_friend_requests': rec_friend_requests,
        'post_count': user_posts.count
    }

    return render(request, "users/profile.html", context)


@login_required
def search_users(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    object_list = User.objects.filter(username__icontains=query)
    context = {
        'users': object_list
    }
    return render(request, "users/search_users.html", context)
```

> models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='user')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("Profile", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/{}".format(self.slug)
```

Comment: share your modes Profile

Comment: class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='user')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("Profile", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/{}".format(self.slug)

Comment: have you run all migrations ?

Comment: yes, python3 manage.py makemigrations and then migrate

Comment: after that did you get any errors or warnings ?

Comment: no, I didn't get any errors, while deleting the friend request that is rejecting the request is working fine but why accept the request isn't working I'm not getting it.

Comment: django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: main.users_profile__old I'm getting this thing

Comment: i have one question:1) in your accept friend request why did not you check whether `frequest` exists before adding to friends ? if `frequest` does not exist  then `frequest.to_user` will give you nothing maybe even an exception maybe

Comment: and try delete all your migrations and make again other migrations.if possible delete all your tables inside the db.

Comment: which line? you telling about

Comment: i tried deleting the database, but stuck with same error